# How to use character code with ::before pseudo element

Tags: html, css, utf-8

I have html with `<meta charset="UTF-8">` and want add *black right-pointing pointer* to `span::before` but it`s not working.

If I simply put &#x25ba to html I would see pointer. But with `content` I see different problems.
I try `content: '►';` - it`s show strange symbol.

Also does not work `'&#x25ba'`, `'\&#x25ba'`, `'\x25ba'`, `'\#x25ba'`, `'\9658'` and other combinations. I can use background-image or something like that, but I don`t want do this.

Maybe you know what I`m doing wrong? Thanks for help!

Comment: Share some of the HTML that you are using for achieving this. A verifiable example would be helpful. Here some infos for adding an example to your question: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`&#9658;` is the unicode for a right pointing arrow

`25B6` or `25BA` is the hex for a right pointing arrow

In CSS you need to escape the hex when using it, see working example

e.g.

```css
span::before {
  content: '\25B6';
}

#span-2::before {
  content: '\25BA';
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<span> Right Pointing Arrow</span>
<br><br>
<span id="span-2"> Another right pointing arrow</span>

<p>&#9658; Unicode Right pointing arrow in HTML</p>
```