# How to use an utf-8 character as a content in css

Tags: css, utf-8

How to use utf-8 character e.g. "âš™" (a ⛮ icon) as background image before?
I tried:  `.icon:before{content:'âš™'}` is not working

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39422891/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/5030551/8620333

Comment: No its not that question

Comment: If you want unicode characters as css background, then it is possible by using svg as background-image. You can use the text element in inline data uri svg and style it however you want.